# How do I disable Stack Overflow AI popup?

Tags: support, popup

How do I disable stack overflow AI popup?

Windows 10, Firefox.

[image]

Things I tried:
modified DOM popup allowed events
installed uBlock Origin

They are very annoying, and I would like to disable them, along with login with GitHub/Facebook/whatever.

Comment: with uBO: right click -> block element

Comment: I believe that once you dismiss the popover, it should stay dismissed as long as you don't clear your cookies or something.

Comment: That doesn't work if you regularly visit in a private window. What's weird is it displays even after I already opted in (but my application is pending).